# Can I Fastclick ReactJS running in Cordova

Tags: cordova, reactjs, fastclick.js

Does [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) work with ReactJS's event system? It doesn't seem to be taking when run through Cordova onto iOS or Android. If not, is there another way of getting the same results. My app has no double-tap functionality so I'd like to remove that delay across the board, if possible...

Answer (score 29):

**Edit**

**Facebook decided to [not add support for defining custom event types](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/436#issuecomment-207624448) and recommend you to use something like [react-tappable](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-tappable)** so you can write something like `<Tappable onTap={}>`.

---

<strike>Facebook's working on a solution in the form of `TapEventPlugin`, but it [won't be made available](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/436) [until they make some decisions](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1170#issuecomment-52123901).</strike>

If you're reading this you're probably working on a project that can't wait until they figure out how they want to publish it.

This repo is for you: https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin

<strike>When Facebook solves [#436](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/436) and [#1170](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1170), this repo will disappear.</strike>

*This solution works for React 0.14.x and 15.x.*

```
npm i -S react-tap-event-plugin
```

Example of usage:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a
        href="#"
        onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Tap Me
      </a>
    );
  },

  handleClick: function(e) {
    console.log("click", e);
  },

  handleTouchTap: function(e) {
    console.log("touchTap", e);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

*Note that with the injector, you will probably need to use only `onTouchTap` (and not `onClick` anymore).*

Comment: FYI, onTouchTap works as a click (for non touchscreen).

Comment: So just to be clear should I use react-tap-event-plugin or React-Tappable now?

Comment: Both works, but react-tappable seems a more reasonable choice. No monkey patching.

Comment: Thanks, probably going that way as react-tap-event-plugin seems to break down with react@15.3.2

Comment: Is this solution required only for mobile browsers?

Answer (score 17):

I got FastClick to work with React, in a Webpack project. A few things seem finicky but it mostly works.  (**Update**: only a toggle switch that was simulating clicks on a hidden checkbox was finicky -- that would be a problem regardless of React). Here's how I turned it on:

`npm install -S fastclick`

In `main.jsx`:

```
import FastClick from 'fastclick';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

So even if you're not using Webpack or Browserify, I'm guessing as long as you can run the load event listener, you'll be fine.

Comment: This worked perfect for me. FWIW, in my isomorphic react app built with webpack, I had to stub out the fastclick module on the server build with
        `new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/fastclick$/i, 'node-noop')`

Comment: @Federico cool, that will be good to know if I have to go isomorphic!

Comment: Soo... I just found out that unfortunately this solution doesnt play nicely with using React's onClick handlers. It only works for your generic html elements -- anchors, buttons, etc. Here's the best I've found: https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  I haven't had any problem with `onClick` handlers.

Comment: Are you creating a React component with an `onClick` prop but not passing it down to the component whatever `render()` returns, so that it ultimately winds up on a real HTML component?  As far as I know, an `onClick` handler on a React component won't do anything, you have to pass it down to an HTML element.

Answer (score 5):

We recently created a React component that is similar to fastclick, except that it’s much simpler and requires a manual callback. It’s pretty short so I’ll post it here:

```js
React.initializeTouchEvents(true)

var TouchClick = React.createClass({

  defaults: {
    touched: false,
    touchdown: false,
    coords: { x:0, y:0 },
    evObj: {}
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.defaults
  },

  handler: function() {
    typeof this.props.handler == 'function' && this.props.handler.apply(this, arguments)
  },

  getCoords: function(e) {
    if ( e.touches && e.touches.length ) {
      var touch = e.touches[0]
      return {
        x: touch.pageX,
        y: touch.pageY
      }
    }
  },

  onTouchStart: function(e) {
    this.setState({ 
      touched: true, 
      touchdown: true,
      coords: this.getCoords(e),
      evObj: e
    })
  },

  onTouchMove: function(e) {
    var coords = this.getCoords(e)
    var distance = Math.max( 
      Math.abs(this.state.coords.x - coords.x), 
      Math.abs(this.state.coords.y - coords.y) 
    )
    if ( distance > 6 )
      this.setState({ touchdown: false })
  },

  onTouchEnd: function() {
    if(this.state.touchdown)
      this.handler.call(this, this.state.evObj)
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ( this.isMounted() )
        this.setState(this.defaults)
    }.bind(this), 4)
  },

  onClick: function() {
    if ( this.state.touched )
      return false
    this.setState(this.defaults)
    this.handler.apply(this, arguments)
  },

  render: function() {
    var classNames = ['touchclick']

    this.props.className && classNames.push(this.props.className)
    this.state.touchdown && classNames.push('touchdown')

    return React.DOM[this.props.nodeName || 'button']({
      className: classNames.join(' '),
      onTouchStart: this.onTouchStart,
      onTouchMove: this.onTouchMove,
      onTouchEnd: this.onTouchEnd,
      onClick: this.onClick
    }, this.props.children)
  }
})
```

Just pass `handler` prop as the callback and wrap your content inside. This also works for systems that has both touch and click events (like newer windows 8 laptops). Example:

```html
 <TouchClick handler={this.clickHandler} className='app'>
   <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </TouchClick>
```

Comment: I mean, this is not a wham-bam-thank-you-maam type solution that instantly gets rid of the annoying click delay for everything on the page, is it?  That's the point of Fastclick

Answer (score 3):

I had issues using David`s method, so as an alternative to FastClick, I implemented a mixin using HammerJs for the event. 
A bit more code to setup the event, but works fine.

```
var HammerClickMixin = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.listeneres = [];

    },
    addTapEvent: function(element,callback) {
        var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element);
        mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }));
        mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'tap', taps: 1 }));
        mc.on('tap',callback);
        this.listeneres.push(mc);
    },
    addDoubleTap : function(element,callback){
        var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element);
        mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }));
        mc.on('doubletap',callback);
        this.listeneres.push(mc);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        for(var i= 0; i < this.listeneres.length; i++){
            this.listeneres[i].destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

This can then be used as as followed:

```
 var Component = React.createClass({
          mixins: [HammerClickMixin],
          componentDidMount: function () {

              this.addTapEvent(this.refs.elementToClick.getDOMNode(),function(){
                  //Handle fast hammer tap!

              });
          },
          render: function () {
               return (
                        <div ref="elementToClick"/>                
                   );
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

It seemed to be working fine in my Cordova app, but there is one significant problem I ran into.

When an element is clicked using React+FastClick, and the next rendered view contains a clickable element in the same position, a onTouchEnd event is also registered in the second element.

I ditched FastClick as I don't want to align my buttons to avoid unwanted behaviour, but I need something to replace it as the click delay feels pretty bad.

Comment: I had similar problems, where a button would be clicked immediately, but then in some environments (android browsers) would be clicked again 300ms later. The tap event plugin used in [react touch libs](https://github.com/petehunt/react-touch-lib/tree/master/src/thirdparty) adds a nice onTouchTap callback but it doesn't work on non-touch inputs. Making a React event plugin might be the way to go though. I still haven't found the answer...

Comment: Thanks for the info, in fact after ditching FastClick I'm still running into similar "tap registers two times" problems, albeit in different parts of the app than previously. Haven't found a solution yet either...

Comment: @PirkkaEsko so FastClick wasn't the cause of the `onTouchEnd` issue you were seeing?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember the details anymore, but my comment above would suggest that FastClick was not the root cause but could have something to do with them, as behaviour was altered (issues were happening in different part of the app after removing FastClick).

Comment: I found this behavior with both fastclick and react-tap-event-plugin. Still haven't found a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `react-fastclick`(https://github.com/JakeSidSmith/react-fastclick) from npm:

```
npm i react-fastclick --save
```

Using it you don't have to change any of your code and it works really nice! You only have to require it once.

```
require('react-fastclick');
```