# Inter Components Communication With React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a very simple react app up-and-running.

The use case is straightforwards: 
An auto-complete component that gets an array of account names, and upon value changed (user has selected the value) - fire event that will display the account.

Here is a code snippet, which I am trying to get work in a way that showAccount method will have access to App's state.

How can I access App's state from `showAccount()` ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';


// Needed for onTouchTap
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015469/988941
injectTapEventPlugin();

import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {accounts: []}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ accounts: [
      {account_name: "foo", account_id: 1},
      {account_name: "bar", account_id: 2}
    ]})
  }

  showAccount (value) {
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
    // `this` points to AutoComplete rather than to App
    console.log(this.state.accounts)
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="App">
        <center>
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText="account name"
          filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
          dataSource={this.state.accounts.map((account) => account.account_name)}
          onUpdateInput={this.showAccount}
        /></center>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: { this.showAccount.bind(this) }

Comment: @AMacdonald Thanks!! 
Will you set it as answer so I can vote it?

Comment: yay - just did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you miss binding the showAccount method?

Check this code, there's an example of how to bind it, you need to do the same with your showAccount method.

```
class InputExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { text: '' };
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  }

  change(ev) {
    this.setState({ text: ev.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    let { text } = this.state;
    return (<input type="text" value={text} onChange={this.change} />);
  }
}
```

**In ECMAScript 2015 classes you need to bind your methods manually.**

I don't have time to expand more, because I'm at work, but check this article

http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/
 **Check the ECMAScript 2015 classes section**
*The sample code is from that post*

Regards

Comment: @Tzury Bar Yochay this is the corect way to do things - you should bind in the constructor and not in the render method otherwise you'll take a performance hit by binding every time the view is rendered

Answer (score 1):

bind your call to the App scope:

{ this.showAccount.bind(this) }

should work!