# Is It Possible To Trigger Contained Component's render from within the Container in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I got `App` which implements a `componentDidMount` and `render`.

App contains 2 components, one, an `AutoComplete` input, and the other is a `CardView`.

The plans is that once a user have chosen an item from the `AutoComplete` list, to display it in the `CardView`

I wonder how would I trigger `CardView`'s render (i.e. setting it's state) from within the `AutoComplete` event handler.

See the line that reads:

**// willing to trigger CardView's render right here.**

In the code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';


// Needed for onTouchTap
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015469/988941
injectTapEventPlugin();

import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {accounts: []}
    this.showAccount = this.showAccount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ accounts: [
      {account_name: "foo", account_id: 1},
      {account_name: "bar", account_id: 2}
    ]})
  }

  showAccount (value) {
    // willing to trigger CardView's render right here.
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="App">
        <center>
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText="account name"
          filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
          dataSource={this.state.accounts.map((account) => account.account_name)}
          onUpdateInput={this.showAccount}
        /></center>
        <CardView />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

Comment: why not pass props to the card? This way you can setState in your show account function and pass that state down to the card.

Comment: @usedToBeFat at declaration time, the chosen value is known. How to I refer to Card's props from within the `showAccount` handler?

Comment: in your question you state that once a user choose an item from the auto complete list you want to display said item. If I understood that correctly, then you don't need the card's render method. All you need it to call setState which will cause another render, and this time the card will get props that it will display. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @usedToBeFat - if you can use my code to explain what you mean that will be the best.

Comment: ok will work on that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer based on how I understand your question.

```
class CardView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.account) {
      return (
        <p>{this.props.account.account_name}</p>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <p>no data</p>
      )
    }

  }
}
  class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {accounts: [], infoToDisplay: ''}
    this.showAccount = this.showAccount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ accounts: [
      {account_name: "foo", account_id: 1},
      {account_name: "bar", account_id: 2}
    ]})
  }

  showAccount (value) {
    let infoToDisplay = this.state.infoToDisplay;
    infoToDisplay = value;
    this.setState({infoToDisplay}); 
    // this line will cause a rerender after the user has chosen something
    // from the autoComplete list
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="App">
        <center>
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText="account name"
          filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
          dataSource={this.state.accounts.map((account) => account.account_name)}
          onUpdateInput={this.showAccount}
        /></center>
        <CardView accounts={this.state.infoToDisplay} /> 
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

what I have done, is give the app component state to keep track of the user's selection. I then pass this state as props to the card component. 
When the state is full card will show it, so in the showAccount function i call setState on infoToDisplay which causes another render, now the card's props will be full with the latest info and display it.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Why are you doing `let infoToDisplay = this.state.infoToDisplay; infoToDisplay = value; this.setState({infoToDisplay});` instead of `this.setState({infoToDisplay: value});`?

Comment: out of habbit. Like when i have an object in state that is getting filled by an onChange.

Comment: would you be able to edit your question to show your code for the card?

Comment: ok just to make sure that the issue isnt the obvious, I called the prop infoToDisplay, yet you are expecting account.