# Update child's state from another child of parent

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a parent that has two children.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <SaveCart />
        <ImportCart carts={response.items || []}/>
    </div>,
    newContainer
);
```

SaveCart is only a component and renders only a Button which handles a prompt modal asks a name and save it via xhr request.
http://kopy.io/rlzn0

ImportCart is another component that renders only a Button which handles a modal dialog of saved carts, and import them on a Shopping Cart functionality.http://kopy.io/mlK5w

The thing I want is if my saved carts are empty, when a cart is saved via SaveCart component I want to update the carts prop or state in ImportCart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773676/is-it-possible-to-trigger-contained-components-render-from-within-the-container/40774185#40774185 This answer might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to have the `items` stored in the state of parent and pass
   them as props to `SaveCart` and `ImportCart`.
2. Whenever user saves an item via `SaveCart`, pass it through a
   `callback` to the parent and let the parent modify its items (and
   add the new one).
3. This will trigger a state change and rerender of `ImportCart`.