# Unable to draw MenuIcon Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build [IconMenu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu) on the `AppBar` Component. I am building my project using [create-react-app](https://gith).

My code looks like
`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu/IconMenu';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton/IconButton';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';

const AppMenu = () => {
    return (
        <IconMenu
            iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
            anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
            targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}>
            <MenuItem primaryText="Menus"/>
            <MenuItem primaryText="Summary"/>
        </IconMenu>
    );
};

const App = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <AppBar
            title="SpicyVeggie"
            showMenuIconButton={false}
            iconElementRight={<AppMenu />}
        />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

I run my application

```
$ yarn start
Compiled successfully!

The app is running at:

  http://localhost:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn run build.
```

and do not see any errors on the console. On the browser, I see

[image]ub.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

I see `warning` and when I click on `MenuIcon` on the right, nothing happens, can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

The code is available in `menu` branch at https://github.com/hhimanshu/spicyveggie/tree/menu

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I needed `react-tap-event-plugin` in order for this to work

I did the following

```
$ npm i --save react-tap-event-plugin
```

and then in `index.js`, I did

```
// other imports
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import App from './App'

// Needed for onTouchTap
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015469/988941
injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and that's it!