# Is Shrinkwrap preventing me from updating react and react-dom?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom

I am trying to update react from 15.4.2 to 16.2.0. Main dependencies I am concerned about is React and React-Dom. I am trying to run: `npm uninstall --save react react-dom` and then `npm install --save react react-dom` however I keep getting the message: `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.2.0 react-dom@16.2.0` so this makes me think it's a shrink or tied down dependency but can't seem to find it. I have tried to even remove react and react-dom from the dependencies in package.json. Still no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Issue:

My root issue is I coudn't run material ui components with tap react and more specifically the Tabs and it's touch/tap feature. Real problem is I believe I had other `node_modules,package.jsons` in root folder where my app/components were in so more than one `node_module` and `package.json` files and folders which caused the clash.

To resolve:

1. Make a copy of your business logic from app where you cannot update
2. Then navigate into/create new directory and
   Scaffolded new react project in there (react-app or in my case Yo @microsoft/sharepoint)
3. Checked the react, reactdom versions in node_modules folder and package.json from within the application that's not updating to see if they're latest versions...they weren't so I did the following updates:

   3.2. `npm install --save react react-dom` (you may have to run `npm uninstall react react-dom` first)

   3.3. `npm install material-ui@latest`

   3.4  `npm i --save react-tap-event-plugin@3.0.2`
4. Check if versions have updated in folders above in step 3...they have now.
5. Try to import and create tap react app components again e.g. Tabs and now it should work

Conclusion:
It was not Shrinkwrap itself that was causing the issue but the duplication of node_module files and/or package.json files. See [Material-UI Tabs have stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624487/material-ui-tabs-have-stopped-working) for more info.

Also remember Create React app will not work with some versions of React and React Dom. So be wary of this.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:

- check the version of `react` and `react-dom` inside the `node_modules/` folder
- remove `node_modules/` and reinstall it again to remove any stall dependencies

Comment: I have tried that too. Sorry but does this info help: Could be that my app let's say called appA (app.js,package.json,node_modules) lives in a parent folder under but this itself has it's own (src,app.js,package.json,node_modules etc.) and a the class here means for every child (appA,appB) that has (node_modules,package.json) in parent I delete I will still have to amend the parent folder files too?? If so it could be something I overseen as a rookie!

Comment: If you know fix please let me know. Until then best idea I have is to create new project OUTSIDE of parent i.e. there will be no node_modules or wrapping files. Then navigate to new project reinstall react,reactdom,materialui etc..all and slowly copying the business logic back in from repo/source control....painful but may be only fix for me.