# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I am new to React Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
// Needed for onTouchTap
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015469/988941
/* eslint-disable import/first */
injectTapEventPlugin();
import './App.css';
import Loginscreen from './Loginscreen'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      loginPage:[],
      uploadScreen:[]
    }
  } 
  componentWillMount(){
    var loginPage =[];
    loginPage.push(<Loginscreen parentContext={this}/>);
    this.setState({
                  loginPage:loginPage
                    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.loginPage}
        {this.state.uploadScreen}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15,
};
export default App;
```

If i have this line in my code 
           **/* eslint-disable import/first */  (in line 5)***
then i get an error
          **'React' must be in scope when using JSX**
but if i remove
       **/ eslint-disable import/first */**
then i get following error
       **Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first**
Can you please help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Here is my LoginScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Login from './Login';
class Loginscreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      username:'',
      password:'',
      loginscreen:[],
      loginmessage:'',
      buttonLabel:'Register',
      isLogin:true
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    var loginscreen=[];
    loginscreen.push(<Login parentContext={this} appContext={this.props.parentContext}/>);
    var loginmessage = "Not registered yet, Register Now";
    this.setState({
                  loginscreen:loginscreen,
                  loginmessage:loginmessage
                    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="loginscreen">
        {this.state.loginscreen}
        <div>
          {this.state.loginmessage}
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div>
               <RaisedButton label={this.state.buttonLabel} primary={true} style={style} onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}/>
           </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15,
};
export default Loginscreen;
```

Comment: How the `LoginScreen` component looks like? Maybe **React** import is missing there.

Comment: import React, {Component} from 'react';
 I have this at start of  LoginScreen

Comment: The error shows src/App.js file have import/first issue

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have all your imports before injectTapEventPlugin(); ?